# Exists someway to update dock preferences plist without killall Dock?

Tags: dock, swift

`AppleSpacesSwitchOnActivate` is represented by the second button on print below

[image]

In the code below, I get the current value and after I change. This can be tested in terminal with

defaults read -g AppleSpacesSwitchOnActivate

```
// getting value of AppleSpacesSwitchOnActivate
let switchOnActivate = CFPreferencesCopyAppValue("AppleSpacesSwitchOnActivate" as CFString, ".GlobalPreferences" as CFString)
print(switchOnActivate as! Bool)

// setting value of AppleSpacesSwitchOnActivate to false
CFPreferencesSetAppValue("AppleSpacesSwitchOnActivate" as CFString, false as CFBoolean, ".GlobalPreferences" as CFString)
CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(".GlobalPreferences" as CFString)
```

Basically, the value `AppleSpacesSwitchOnActivate` is changed, but the change is not effective until `killall Dock`.

Is there some way to update dock preferences plist without `killall Dock`?

Comment: What's wrong with killing the dock process? You can do that in Swift as well.

Comment: When dock process is killed, all minimized windows are exposed. I want to evit this behavior